# How can I convert string dates with arabic characters to english string dates? preferably by using DateTime

Tags: python, python-datetime

This is an example Arabic date: (٢٠٢٢-٠٦-٠٤T٠٥:١٠:٠٢+03:00) when I try to convert it from iso format
to a regular readable date it gives this error

```
date = '٢٠٢٢-٠٦-٠٤T٠٥:١٠:٠٢+03:00'
date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date)
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '٢٠٢٢-٠٦-٠٤T٠٥:١٠:٠٢+03:00'
```

I need to translate Arabic numbers into regular numbers in order for this to work, I have tested google translating this date to english and it worked so it is possible. I couldn't find a way to do this using datetime.

Comment: It looks like Arabic digits to me.

Comment: first translate your text using python package 'translate' and then use datetime

Comment: "Arabic date" is a little confusing, since it sounds like you could mean the date in the Hijri calendar. This is just an ISO date using Arabic digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
date = '٢٠٢٢-٠٦-٠٤T٠٥:١٠:٠٢+03:00'
date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(unidecode(date))
```